# +24V supply versus +/- 12V supply

Tags: voltage, cmos

In CMOS mix-signal circuitry, would it make a difference if I set Vdd to 24V and Vss to 0, instead of having +/- 12V supply rails?

I know voltage is just a reference, but do the absolute numbers matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will matter only if you have a connection that uses the "ground" at 0V in a +/-12V system. If you have only connections that use the +/-12V rails but never touch the 0V ground then yes you can a 0 to 24V power supply. Obviously, if you have a line that uses 0V in a +/-12V system you could substitute that with a 12V line in a 0-24V system. As you said, voltage is just a reference. It's all about the difference.

Comment: It's also about which of the signals in the system gets connected to the chassis (aka "chassis ground"), if any.